# Why is the function `SumConvergence` not valid for simple power series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation, convergence

I want to find the convergence interval of function $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{n}+(-2)^{n}} \frac{x^{n}}{n}$.

```
Sum[(1/(3^n + (-2)^n))*(x^n/n), {n, 1, Infinity}]
SumConvergence[(1/(3^n + (-2)^n))*(x^n/n), n]
```

The above code can not get the convergence interval of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{n}+(-2)^{n}} \frac{x^{n}}{n}$, but we can easily calculate the convergence radius of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{n}+(-2)^{n}} \frac{x^{n}}{n}$ by using the  convergence checking method:

```
Limit[1/(3^(n + 1) + (-2)^(n + 1))/(1/(3^n + (-2)^n)), n -> Infinity]
```

I want to know why the function `SumConvergence` is not valid for a simple power series  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{3^{n}+(-2)^{n}} \frac{x^{n}}{n}$.

Under the prompt of **Michael E2**, I can judge the convergence at the end point by ratio discrimination:

```
Limit[((-3)^n/(3^n + (-2)^n) 1/n)/((-1)^n/n), n -> Infinity]
Limit[n (3^n/(3^n + (-2)^n) 1/n), n -> Infinity]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
SumConvergence[(1/(3^n + (-2)^n))*(x^n/n), n, Method -> "RatioTest"]
```

> ```
> Abs[x] < 3
> ```

I found it by Reading The _ Manual, actually.

Comment: But the point of `x = 3` is also convergent. However, the above results do not include the case of `x = 3`.

Comment: @Montevideo The Ratio Test does not apply to endpoints, only to the radius of convergence.  Also, it's a complex disk, so there are other points to check as well, I think. -- Maybe this is the problem: `SumConvergence[(1/(3^n + (-2)^n))*(x^n/n) /. x -> 3, n]`

Comment: `SumConvergence[(1/(3^n + (-2)^n))*(x^n/n) /. x -> -3 I, n]` doesn't work either.

Comment: I don't know why function `SumConvergence` can't judge whether `x = 3` converges or not, but `Limit[(1/(3^n + (-2)^n) 3^n/n), n -> Infinity]` can give a reasonable result.

Comment: @Montevideo That's the n-th term test, and all it shows is that it fails to show divergence.  Multiplying the term by `n` gives an indeterminate result (limit = 1): `Limit[n (1/(3^n + (-2)^n) 3^n/n), n -> Infinity]`.

Comment: Thank you. But `Limit[n^2 ((-3)^n/(3^n + (-2)^n) 1/n), n -> Infinity]` gets a strange result (`x = - 3` should be a convergence point).

Comment: Multiplying by `n^2` is too big.  If the limit is finite, then good, it's convergent; otherwise it's indeterminate.  Mutliplying by `n^(1+e)` for any `e > 1` has the same issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I found the ratio function wrong just now.